# DOMPDF not working on server

Tags: opencart, dompdf

I have included the files properly as shown below,

```
require_once DIR_ROOT . '/vendor/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
```

I'm creating object as mentioned in one of the tutorial

```
// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');
```

This is working fine on my localhost. But It is failinng to create object $dompdf = new Dompdf(); on our server. I'm using opencart.

Comment: Failing in what way? Any PHP errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after installing mb_string module on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggled more than one month to solve this finally solved...
solution is

```
 <?php
    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    // reference the Dompdf namespace
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;

    ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sucess</h1>
</body>
</html>

    <?php

    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    //$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    //For view
    $dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
    // for download
    //$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes localhost code is not work on the server. I solved it.**

change the php version to 7 and test.